# JavaScript function on page load

Tags: javascript

I need to change the Div id "**Div01**" state to "**highlight**" class when the page loads.
 
Please see the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div01"><a href="#" class="btn" onclick="roleActive(this);">user</a></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var role; function roleActive(obj){ if (role)
role.className = 'btn';
obj.className = 'highlight';
role = obj;}
```

CSS:

```
.btn{
display:block;
height:25px;
width:100px;
padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
font-size:16px;} 

.highlight{
cursor:default;
display:block;
height:25px;
width:100px;
padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align:center;
font-size:16px;
background-color:#FFF;
border-bottom:4px solid #F0AB00;
color:#000;
text-decoration:underline;}

a.btn:link{background-color:#000;color:#FFF;}
a.btn:visited{background-color:#000;color:#FFF;}
a.btn:hover,active{background-color:#FFF;color:#000;text-decoration:underline; border-bottom:4px solid #F0AB00;}
```

Kindly help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        roleActive(document.getElementById('div01').children[0]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really worked for me :).<br> I have one more query but it hard to explain here. How can i create it using the fiddle.net

Comment: Hi @Arun, Please find the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/aki_shaitan/ruDek/. <br/> In this i want a function that when i click on "**Button 01**" it should open its submenu"**01**". After this when click on some other button, it should it hide the previous submenu and open the relevant submenu.

Comment: @Ankit it will be better if you post it as a separate question'

Comment: I am facing some issue with this script because i made some changes in the functionality. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('div01').className = 'highlight'
}
```

or

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('div01').className = 'highlight'
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
exampleCall();
function exampleCall()
{
 document.getElementById('div01').className = 'highlight'
}
</script>
```

Comment: using this function, the class "**highlight**" gets changed but still i can see the "**.btn**" class on top.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('div01').className = 'highlight';
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('div01').className = 'highlight';
}
```

For Jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#div01').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick event is sending 'this' to the function, but it's the onclick event of the , not of the . Is this what you intended?

Since you're not using the inherent click functionality of the  then I'd suggest getting rid of it. Just have the click event on the , so clicking it will fire roleActive() and apply the classes appropriately.